# How to use a key file as public key in RSA encryption?

Tags: react-native, rsa

I am exploring [react-native-rsa-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa-native) package.
My problem statement is:
I need to encrypt a string using a public key but that key is in file format not is a string. Which I have put in the asset directory.
How can I use this file (mypublickey.key) in react-native code to encrypt the data?

```
RSA.encrypt(message, publicKey)
```

Comment: You should include at least some parts (e.g. if it is a text file some lines of the beginning and before end) of the key file on your question, otherwise we don't know what key format is used.